# What does `class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window` mean?

Tags: c++, class

I'm following the Gtk "Hello World" tutorial found [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-helloworld.html.en), and I've come across a line in a class declaration I've never seen before (I've only been learning to program for a few months now), and I was wondering if someone could please explain it to me. The line is the

```
class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
```

I know what `class HelloWorld` is doing, but I've never seen the `public Gtk::Window` before. The full header file is provided for reference.

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H

#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{

public:
  HelloWorld();
  virtual ~HelloWorld();

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_button_clicked();

  //Member widgets:
  Gtk::Button m_button;
};

#endif // GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `HelloWorld` is derived from `Gtk::Window`, so it inherits its behaviour.

`HelloWorld` represents a Gtk window, so it is just natural to have it derive from the Gtk's window class. It's constructor will probably add a button to the window (the actual window is created by the parent class constructor, which is invoked automatically when a new instance of `HelloWorld` is created …) and connect a signal handler (`on_button_clicked`) to the window.

You can call all of `Gtk::Window`'s methods through an instance of `HelloWorld`. In turn, `HelloWorld` can override virtual methods of `Gtk::Window` to change its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> `class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window`

This means the class `HelloWorld` is publically [derived](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) from class `Window` defined inside `Gtk` namespace. `Gtk::Window` is the fully qualified name of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that you should either be using the 3.0 branch of gtkmm or you should use the stable branch of the tutorial.[link text](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/)

The 3.0 branch of gtkmm is still under development, and you should expect a few "surprises" now and then.