# What does class `expr_t : public ast_container` mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does `class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478481/what-does-class-helloworld-public-gtkwindow-mean)

I'm new to C++, but looked at a few tutorials and read partially Accelerated C++ ... but have seen something like

```
class expr_t : public ast_container {
public:
    virtual double eval() const = 0;
    ...
```

What does the 1st line mean? Its declaring a class named `expr_t`? Then whats `ast_container` part?

Then on line 3: `virtual double eval() const = 0` what does it mean?

- Seems like its declaring a virtual function called `eval` that returns a double, but then whats the `const = 0` part?

Comment: Was the chapter on inheritance?

Comment: The `const` and `= 0` are two different parts. Anyway, I'm sure the book explains this as you go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the parent class/super class/(whatever one calls it) of the `expr_t` class is the `ast_container` class. At first glance, it roughly means that everything `ast_container` can do, `expr_t` can do it as well, and something more too.